# Visual Studio C# Plot a Local Map

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-maps, plot, gps

I have a GPS module that give me GPS value. I crop an image of a map(Google) around my area. I want to use the image(map) and plot it from the GPS value with visual studio c# (winform) locally without connecting to the internet. Any sample code so that I can start the project? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

without internet it may not possible.
and one more thing that you must have location access from your device.